# Trying to unzip a file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, compression

I'm trying to unzip a bunch of archives including the new xlsx files into a TMP folder and then work on that folder and then remove it. And shit just doesnt want to go my way.

```
$spath = "C:\_PS\TestFolder"
$destination=”C:\TestFolder\Testzip"

Get-ChildItem $spath -include *.xlsx -Recurse  | foreach-object  {
    # Remove existing TMP folder and create a new one
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $destination
    New-Item $destination -type directory

    $archiveFile = $_.fullname | out-string -stream

    "Extract this: " + $archiveFile
    "To here: " + $destination

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($archiveFile)
    $destinationFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($destination)
    $destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items())

}
```

And it always gives me these errors

```
Exception calling "NameSpace" with "1" argument(s): "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))" At C:\_PS\FindCC.ps1:62 char:46
+     $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace <<<< ($archiveFile)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\_PS\FindCC.ps1:64 char:50
+     $destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items <<<< ())
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Items:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Easy. http://vcsjones.com/2012/11/11/unzipping-files-with-powershell-in-server-core-the-new-way/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script works fine for ZIP files:

```
Get-ChildItem $spath -include *.zip -Recurse
```

I'm not sure why you're using:

```
 -include *.xlsx
```

as this is *excluding* your archive files.  If you want to *move* XLSX files then you'll need to write another block of code to handle the file move.

Comment: xlsx files are just zipped xml files so unzip does/should work

Comment: Yes they are, and it does work if you rename the file extension to ZIP before trying to unpack it - not sure why xlsx aren't 'seen' as archives.

Comment: Copy file to temp, rename file, extract file, do stuff with file, remove temp file and folder. Think thats the order of business then :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function Extract-Zip 
{ 
    param([string]$zipfilename, [string] $destination) 
    if(test-path($zipfilename)) 
    { 
        $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application 
        $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename) 
        $destinationFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($destination) 
        $destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items()) 
    }
    else 
    {   
        Write-Host $zipfilename "not found"
    }
}
```

**Use of the function:**
Suppose u want to extract a zip file of name "myzip.zip" into a directory "C:\myFolder".
Make sure "C:\myFolder" directory exists, then run `Extract-Zip C:\myzip.zip C:\myFolder`